# assertion is failing on contains condition in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

using a JSR223 assertion for a JSON response where I am validating a field `customerID`, which contains the below list of `customerID`,

```
GSK
CLINIRX
KENDLE
Test
TestIc2
Test692
TesteDe
Test2zY
TestEjC
Testb5b
Testhke
TestcI4
Test2zY
Test7x7
TesteDe
TestU4x
Testfkv
TestHea
TestEjC
```

The `Test<random 3 characters are generating at the run time while executing the script>`, but the first 4 letter is `Test` is fixed.
Assertion Script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    customerID = jsonResponse.customerId;           
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}
if (customerID.contains('Test') ||customerID.contains('KENDLE') || customerID.contains('CLINIRX') || customerID.contains('GSK')){
                AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
            }
            else {
                AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
                AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);          }
```

How to solve this, if the customerID contain `Test<3 char>` should also pass, as this is failing for few?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note:  According to Java Doc, `String contains() method is used to check whether the specific set of characters are part of the given string or not. It returns a boolean value true if the specified characters are substring of a given string and returns false otherwise. It can be directly used inside the if statement.`

Now solution to your problem:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    customerID = jsonResponse.customerId;           
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}
if (customerID.contains("Test") ||customerID.contains('KENDLE') || customerID.contains('CLINIRX') || customerID.contains('GSK')){
                AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
            }
            else {
                AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
                AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);          }
```

Another Note: single quotes bracket a string literal; the value of the literal is the value within the quotes. When double quotes are used, any references to variables or expressions within the quotes are interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, my expectation is that something is wrong with your `customerID` variable

So I would suggest trying printing it to the [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file using [`log` shorthand for the `Log4jLogger` class](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy):

```
customerID = jsonResponse.customerId;
log.info('Current customer ID value: ' +  customerID)
```

Then in case of failure you can look into the log file and see why it failed. The [contains() function](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) itself shouldn't be a problem, my expectation is that either your `customerID` variable doesn't contain what you're looking for or it's just [null](https://dev.to/dj_devjournal/understanding-null-in-java-4o31).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to validate the customer IDs

```
(GSK|CLINIRX|KENDLE|Test([A-Za-z0-9]{3})?)
```